# Differentiability of a Linear Functional on a Normed Linear Space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(V,\|.\|)$ be a normed linear space.
The function $F: V\to R$ is differentiable at $w \in V$ if there is a $F_w \in V^*$ (the dual space) s.t.
$$
\lim_{h \to 0 \in V}\frac{\|F(w+h)-F(w)-F_w(h)\|}{\|h\|}=0 \in R
$$

Suppose $F:V \to R$ is linear. Is $F$ differentiable everywhere?

The following theorem can be used directly:

Theorem:

If the $F$ above is differentiable at $w$, then the $F_w$ above is uniquely defined:
$$
F_w(h)=\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{F(w+th)-F(w)}{t}
$$

My attempt: we don't know. I applied the theorem above to characterize $F_w$ and found that $F_w(h)=F(h)$. But $F(h)$ isn't necessarily in $V^*$. Thus, we don't know if $F$ is differentiable.

Comment: A linear functional need not be continuous so it need not be differentiable. However it is differentiable everywhere (with $F_{w}=F$) if it is assumed to be continuous.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you give me feedback on my attempt?